# Printing long long integer accurately when using power function in C++

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain how to print the accurate value?

```
int main() {
    std::cout << pow(2,53);
}
//output=9.0072e+15
```

Comment: There is no error, this is scientific notation for floating point numbers, as `pow` returns `double` or `float`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/

Comment: Ya,but how to  print the accurate number efficiently?
My way of doing this:
    int main() {
    long long int k=pow(2,53);
    std::cout << k;
}
But is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Without having tried it, from the above link I would guess it's `cout.setf(std::ios::fixed)`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort, no searching.

Answer (score 1):

`pow()` takes `double` as parameters instead of integers. Luckily, this is precisely representable by `unsigned long long`, and 2<sup>53</sup> = (1 << 53).

Therefore, you could use

```
std::cout << (1ULL << 53);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want not to use bit shift (<<) you can forcibly use accurate type 'long long':

```
long long x = pow(2, 53);
cout << x;
```